# Order of block number in Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Assume I started a transaction yesterday which is not yet confirmed (In **Pending** status).
Later four other transactions are Successful and assumed they are having block numbers
1110, 1111, 1112, 1113.

Assume the old transaction got confirmed at this point in time. May I know what can be the block number of that old one? Can it be less than 1110 or it will be greater than 1113.
I tested but my transactions are fast and unable to generate this scenario.

The reason for asking is, to read ether scan data using block numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tx will be in a higher block (Assuming it gets accepted by a miner at some point). It is currently in the mempool waiting to be mined. You can query the blockchain to get the status (Depends on client API, special clients like Alchemy and QuickNode may have special tools to explore the mempool e.g. Alchemy have a mempool watcher).

[This](https://chainstack.com/a-developers-guide-to-the-transactions-in-mempool-metamask-edition/) is a good primer to understand what is happening.